# Play Scala ReactiveMongo like query

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

Hello i have problem i got repo and controler witch returns all object in colection but i wannt to do search in colection in "adress" field my data looks like "adres" "Some adres " booknr "booknr" i wantt to create rest returns items that have some "string" in field adres here is my code

```
trait BooksRepo {
  def find()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[JsObject]]

  def findbyquery()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[JsObject]]

  def update(selector: BSONDocument, update: BSONDocument)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[WriteResult]

  def remove(document: BSONDocument)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[WriteResult]

  def save(document: BSONDocument)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[WriteResult]
}

class BooksMongoRepo(reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends PostRepo {
  // BSON-JSON conversions
  import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._

  protected def collection =
    reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("books")
//  val query = Json.obj("adres" -> Json.obj({$regex: /^ABC/i}))


  def find()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[JsObject]] =
    collection.find(Json.obj()).cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.Primary).collect[List]()

//  def findbyquery()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[JsObject]]= collection.find(query).cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.Primary).collect[List]()
```

Controler returns all books

```
 def list = Action.async { implicit request =>
    booksRepo.find()
      .map(posts => Ok(Json.toJson(posts.reverse)))
      .recover { case PrimaryUnavailableException => InternalServerError("Please install MongoDB") }
  }
```

Comment: i got new query : val query = Json.obj("$regex" ->  (".*" + "\\Qa\\E" + ".*")) >>unexpected conversion BSONRegex

Comment: Quite unclear to me. Do you have tried the query in Mongo shell first? What are the used versions? Do you get an error?

Comment: working query > { "adres": { $regex: '.*\QKrakow\E.*', $options: 'i' } } > how to write in reactivemongo

Comment: Could you please write complete sentense?

Comment: Just did it now here is code > def findbyquery()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[JsObject]]= collection.find(Json.obj("adres" -> Json.obj("$regex" -> ".*\\Qa\\E.*", "$options" -> "i")))
  .cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.Primary).collect[List]()

Comment: With the Play JSON serialisation `Json.obj("address" -> Json.obj("$regex" -> """.*\QKrakow\E.*""", "$options" -> "i"))`

Comment: Take care about the escape char in your regex